# Stored Procedure to generate IDs returning duplicate values

Tags: java, sql, spring, sybase, spring-transactions

I'm currently working in a legacy application that uses an Stored Procedure in a Sybase DB to generate some IDs incrementally. The procedure is defined as:

```
CREATE PROC getId
(@val int = -1 output) 
AS
BEGIN
UPDATE ID_TABLE SET LAST_VALUE = LAST_VALUE + 1
SELECT @val = LAST_VALUE FROM ID_TABLE
RETURN @val
END
```

This procedure is being called from a Java application using Spring's `TransactionTemplate` to handle the transaction in a declarative manner.

```java
public Integer getId() {
    TransactionTemplate txTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(txManager); // txManager is an autowired instance of PlatformTransactionManager.
    txTemplate.setIsolationLevel(TransactionDefinition.ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE);
    txTemplate.setTimeout(-1);
    return (Integer) txTemplate.execute((TransactionCallback) status -> idDao.generateId());
}
```

Internally, *idDao* uses a `JdbcTemplate` to call the Stored Procedure using a `CallableStatementCreatorFactory`. Nothing too out of the ordinary there.

The Stored Procedure is called ~10k times/day. From time to time, we see some ID collisions. My understanding was that the isolation level being set to *SERIALIZABLE* should prevent this from happening, and I can't seem to reproduce this even calling `getId` simultaneously with several threads. Does anybody have a hint on what might be happening here?

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to the java/spring coding but on a purely SQL basis it looks and sounds like the `update/select` is not being performed within a transaction.

Without a transaction wrapper (eg, explicit `begin/commit tran`, `autocommit=false`, `set chained on`) the `update/select` is a prime target for a race condition and duplicate key errors.

**NOTE:** the isolation level has no effect if the `update/select` is performed outside of a transaction wrapper

Tracking down a 'missing transaction wrapper' issue is a good idea as there could be other pieces of SQL code suffering from poor/missing transaction management.  Having said that ...

For this particular case one easy fix would be to add a transaction wrapper in the proc, eg:

```
CREATE PROC getId
(@val int = -1 output) 
AS
BEGIN

begin tran
    UPDATE ID_TABLE SET LAST_VALUE = LAST_VALUE + 1
    SELECT @val = LAST_VALUE FROM ID_TABLE
commit tran

RETURN @val
END
```

Even better would be a rewrite of the `update` that eliminates the need for the `select`, eg:

```
CREATE PROC getId
(@val int = -1 output) 
AS
BEGIN

UPDATE ID_TABLE SET @val=LAST_VALUE+1, LAST_VALUE = LAST_VALUE + 1

RETURN @val
END
```

**NOTE:** as a standalone operation this eliminates the need for a transaction wrapper and should eliminate the generation of duplicate keys (assuming this proc is the root cause of the duplicate key issue)

Assuming this is `Sybase ASE` I'd want to look at making sure the table is configured to use `datarows` locking; with `allpages` locking, and to a limited extent `datapages` locking, there's a chance of a race condition on index updates (which in turn could lead to a deadlock scenario).